# How to fix roller shade that pulled out of top window frame

Tags: windows, screws, drywall-anchor, blinds, hole-repair

My roller shade is mounted in the top inside of the window frame. The shades were here when we moved in. One of the plastic anchor screws broke off in the drywall, and the bracket pulled out of the ceiling. My question is, can I replace the old screws with Twist-N-Lock 50 lb. Self-Drilling Drywall Anchors with Screws (1-1/4 in. pan-head philips screws from Home Depot) without repairing the drywall? Or will it just pull out again? The old anchors were just straight plastic anchors with a 1/2" screw.

Comment: Some photos would help!

Answer (score 0):

Those anchors should work for you. Remove the old anchors so you just have the small hole in the drywall. Since you're using 1-1/4" screws, stick a small screwdriver into the holes and make sure you've got enough space up there to accommodate the anchors and screws. Follow the directions and snug those anchors pretty tight.